# sort calculation data to rank my data in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, rank, rate

How can I sort my data to give rate like 5 stars, 4 stars, until 1 stars.

This is my query

```
function top5cust($tahun, $bulan)
{
    if ($tahun == 'semua' && $bulan == 'semua'){
        $data = $this->db->query("SELECT nama_jalan, no_rumah, jarak, kelurahan, kecamatan, kota, COUNT(*) as freq 
                                from t_cust GROUP by nama_jalan, no_rumah, jarak,kelurahan, kecamatan, kota 
                                ORDER by freq DESC LIMIT 5");

    }
    else
    {

        $data = $this->db->query("SELECT nama_jalan, no_rumah, jarak, kelurahan, kecamatan, kota, COUNT(*) as freq 
                                from t_cust
                                WHERE YEAR(tgl_req) = $tahun AND MONTH(tgl_req) = $bulan
                                group by nama_jalan, no_rumah, jarak, jarak,kelurahan, kecamatan, kota 
                                ORDER by freq DESC LIMIT 5");
    }           
    return $data->result();     
}
```

and this is my php code

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th><center>Alamat</center></th>
    <th><center>Jarak</center></th>
    <th><center>Frekuensi</center></th>

    <th><center>Rate</center></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php

    $cost=2000;
    $totalbeli=50000;

    foreach($top5cust as $data){
        $frekuensi=$data->freq;
        $jaraks=$data->jarak;
        $perhitunganrank=($frekuensi*$totalbeli)-($jaraks*$cost*$frekuensi);


        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$data->nama_jalan." no ".$data->no_rumah.", ".$data->kelurahan.", ".$data->kecamatan.", ".$data->kota."   </td>";
        echo "<td>".$data->jarak."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$data->freq."</td>";
        echo '<td>'.$perhitunganrank.'</td>';
        echo"</tr>";
    }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I sort data and give rate by `$perhitunganrank` but without echo it.
Sorry if my question not clear my english is not good.

regards,
ridho

Comment: also post your input and expected output

Comment: input data from database, and output is table with 4 coloum (alamat, jarak, frekuensi, and Rate). data in table sort by result  of $perhitunganrank Desc sort..

Comment: There is a problem in your query. You need to think about those cases where the user selects only the year but not the month, and vice versa. Otherwise the query will be `where month='semua'` which will either return zero results or an error, depending on the data type of your column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `usort`, you can see the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php an example in your case would be:

```
$cost=2000;
$totalbeli=50000;

//We create an empty array. We need this array because PDO resultsets are iterable objects which means you can't iterate twice

$my_array = array();

//Now we put objects into this empty array. Each row from the resultset will be a new object.

foreach($top5cust as $data){
// The following is a shallow copy (using the keyword 'clone'). It is OK as long as the fields are primitive variables.
    $my_object = clone $data;
    $my_object->perhitunganrank=($my_object->freq*$my_object->totalbeli)-($my_object->jarak*$cost*$my_object->freq);
    array_push($my_array, $my_object);
}

// Now we need to create a function that compares two objects and tells us which one comes first between the two. 
// This function will then be used by usort.
// The function compares using the property perhitunganrank. 

function cmp($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a->perhitunganrank, $b->perhitunganrank);
}

// now we sort based on the function above
usort($my_array, "cmp");

//Finally we print the array of objects which is now sorted.
foreach($my_array as $row_to_print){
    $counter =1;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row_to_print->nama_jalan." no ".$row_to_print->no_rumah.", ".$row_to_print->kelurahan.", ".$row_to_print->kecamatan.", ".$row_to_print->kota."   </td>";
    echo "<td>".$row_to_print->jarak."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row_to_print->frekuensi."</td>";
    echo '<td>'.$row_to_print->perhitunganrank.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$counter.'</td>';
    echo"</tr>";
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: oh god thankyou very much mr. mastazi the code success, its save me.. i have 1 question again, if i want to add 1 colom again  ("ranking") contain numbers that represent of perhitunganrank (ex: biggest value of perhitunganrank represented by number 1, second biggest value represented by number 2, etc)  I hope you can understand my question, thankyou..

Comment: Sure! See my edited answer, I have used the variable $counter, I'm on mobile phone I hope I typed it correctly:-)